# Reusable Field-Configurations

Tags: craft3

In my current website-project I have to repeat myself very often. In several sections / matrix fields I use field configurations like:

- Spacing (Dropdown: small, medium, large)
- Buttons (SuperTable with Linkits)
- ...

The problem is if I add a new spacing option, I have to change multiple field configurations.

Is there an approach to move this field configuration to a "component" and use a "Buttons" field instead of creating a SuperTable field for each section again?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to reuse existing fields, you may want to take a look at the Neo plugin: https://github.com/spicywebau/craft-neo